# Сайт с хостинга на localhost перенаправляет в интернет

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование, хостинг

Перенес свой сайт wordpress с хостинга на localhost, перенаправляет в интернет на мой сайт. Я так понимаю нужно где-то прописать вместо адреса моего сайта с интернета на адрес сайта на локалхост. Подскажите какой документ отвечает за это.

Comment: Насколько я помню эти настройки у WP в базе данных, я в таких случаях менял руками. Но надо еще .htaccess смотреть конечно

Answer (score 2):

Нужно вносить изменения в бд, ниже скрипт для замены, но не серебряная пуля так как если в мета данных сидит домен нужно писать php скрипт который будет заменять эти url ибо используется серилизация

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'z-site.ru', 'localhost');
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid, 'z-site.ru', 'localhost');
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, 'z-site.ru', 'localhost');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, 'z-site.ru', 'localhost');
```

Answer (score 1):

Найти и заменить адрес в файле базы данных вордпресса.
Или править hosts файл в windows.

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь это отвечает .htaccess, поменяй

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

На

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ошибаетесь. А в данном случае это вообще может загнать браузер в мертвый цикл редиректов.